# How to debug a C++ COM dll from a C++ non-COM dll?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, dll, com

Here is the scenario. I am using Visual Studio 2010. I have a C++ COM dll. This dll is used by another C++ dll project which is not a COM project. The second dll exposes API's to client applications. The dependency is Client->Non-COM dll->COM dll. I would like to debug the COM dll from any client application.

Here are the things that I have already tried.

1. Created a C++ win32 console application that makes use of the non-COM dll.
2. Kept both COM dll and non-COM dll and the corresponding pdb files in the debug directory of the win32 application. In Options->Debugging->Symbols, I have selected the path to the debug directory and checked "only specified modules" option to load these files.
3. Set all include and library dependencies.
4. Now, I can successfully run the application. But while debugging, I can navigate only to the non-COM dll by pressing F11 and the same F11 navigation is not working from this dll to the COM dll.
5. When I tried this with two non-COM dll's and a client application, I could navigate upto the innermost dll. At this point, I realized I should change the corresponding registry entry to point to my COM dll file located in the debug directory of the client application, but no luck!

I am sorry that I cannot share the code or describe in detail.

Any solutions?

Comment: Simplest explanation is that you just didn't create the COM object successfully.  Debug + Windows + Modules, ensure you see the COM dll listed there.  Right-click it and select "Symbol Load Information" to see where the debugger looked for the PDB file.

Answer (score 1):

You can set a break-point in your COM dll source code and then attach it to process named '`dllhost.exe`'. Whenever native dll makes a call to COM dll, breakpoint will hit.

Comment: In my case, both native dll and COM dll are in the same solution.

1. I set the COM project as the startup project.
2. Attached dllhost.exe.
3. Set Properties->Debugging->Command to my client application and debugged.

The breakpoint did not hit. Is that what you suggested or am I missing something here?

Comment: Open 2 vs instances, one with native dll n another com dll. Attach com dll project to dllhost. Then start debugging native dll project.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. Both are in the same solution. If I try to open the same solution simultaneously in two instances of VS, the later instance reads "One or more projects were not loaded", of course to avoid any race condition.

Comment: Separate them in two different Visual Studio instances. run them independently.

Answer (score 0):

1. Set the COM dll project as the startup project. Right click on the project. Navigate to Properties->Configuration Properties->Debugging->Command. Enter the complete path to the client application.
   Eg: C:\Users...\Debug\ClientApplication.exe.
2. Register the COM dll by the command ***regsvr32 "pathToCOMDll"*** running windows command prompt as admin. Breakpoint will be hit.
   Eg: regsvr32 "C:\Users...\COMDll.dll" where COMDll.dll is the COM dll. It should not really matter what dll is referencing what dll.

Note: Avoid editing the windows registry directly and try to use regsvr32 command.